# Find three closest element from three different sorted arrays (Difference between two solutions)

Tags: c++, sorting, search, time-complexity, binary-search

//Solution 1

```
void findClosest(int A[], int B[], int C[], int p, int q, int r)
{
 
    int diff = INT_MAX;  // Initialize min diff
 
    // Initialize result
    int res_i =0, res_j = 0, res_k = 0;
 
    // Traverse arrays
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    while (i < p && j < q && k < r)
    {
        // Find minimum and maximum of current three elements
        int minimum = min(A[i], min(B[j], C[k]));
        int maximum = max(A[i], max(B[j], C[k]));
 
        // Update result if current diff is less than the min
        // diff so far
        if (maximum-minimum < diff)
        {
             res_i = i, res_j = j, res_k = k;
             diff = maximum - minimum;
        }
 
        // We can't get less than 0 as values are absolute
        if (diff == 0) break;
 
        // Increment index of array with smallest value
        if (A[i] == minimum) i++;
        else if (B[j] == minimum) j++;
        else k++;
    }
 
    // Print result
    cout << A[res_i] << " " << B[res_j] << " " << C[res_k];
}
```

> //Solution 2

```
void findClosest(int A[], int B[], int C[], int p, int q, int r)
{
```

> //same as solution 1

```
    while (i < p && j < q && k < r)
    {
        // Find minimum and maximum of current three elements
        int minimum = min(A[i], min(B[j], C[k]));
        int maximum = max(A[i], max(B[j], C[k]));
 
        // Calculate the maximum difference for the current combination
        int curDiff = abs(maximum - minimum);
 
        // Update result if current diff is less than the min
        // diff so far
        if (curDiff < diff)
        {
            res_i = i, res_j = j, res_k = k;
            diff = curDiff;
        }
 
        // If the maximum element of A is the smallest among the three,
        // we move the A pointer forward
        if (A[i] == minimum && A[i] <= B[j] && A[i] <= C[k]) i++;
 
        // If the maximum element of B is the smallest among the three,
        // we move the B pointer forward
        else if (B[j] == minimum && B[j] <= A[i] && B[j] <= C[k]) j++;
 
        // If the maximum element of C is the smallest among the three,
        // we move the C pointer forward
        else k++;
    }
 
    // Print result
    cout << A[res_i] << " " << B[res_j] << " " << C[res_k];
}
```

Why is the first solution's time complexity O(p + q + r) but that of second solution O(NLongN). Why is the second solution using binary search if it's not dividing into half?
Isn't the second solution also incrementing the index of the array that contains the minimum element?

Comment: Both solutions are essentially the same in terms of logic and functionality, and they both have a time complexity of O(p + q + r). The difference in time complexity between the two solutions is not due to the difference in the solutions themselves, but rather due to the way they are presented or the additional operations they might be doing.

Comment: Also not this is C++ and you should stop passing "C" style arrays around. Use std::array or std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer but since I made a comment on "C" style coding, here is an example using only C++. This code is should follow the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines).

```
#include <vector>    // <-- resizable C++ array
#include <limits>    // so you don't have to use INT_MAX (from "C")
#include <iostream>

// using namespace std; // do not use this

// the result of a find closest operation
struct find_closest_result_t
{
    int value1;
    int value2;
    int value3;
    int distance = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); // DO NOT USE INT_MAX (that's "C")
};

// in C++ do NOT use "C" style arrays, but use std::vector (dynamic length) or std::array (fixed length)
// pass by reference to avoid copies
// pass by const, since find should never be allowed to modify the content of the vectors
// finding the closest values is like finding the mimimum distance between values

auto find_closest(const std::vector<int>& values1, const std::vector<int>& values2, const std::vector<int>& values3)
{
    find_closest_result_t result;

    // prefer range-based for loops over iterators and or index based for loops, range based for loops cannot go out of bounds
    // nowhere in the calculation do we need the index of the values so range-based for loops it is
    // 
    // Also note this algorithm shows the complexity is O(n^3) as shown by the three nested loops
    // (I did not go looking for an efficient algorithm, because my goal is to show current C++ in action)
    
    for (const auto value1 : values1)
    {
        for (const auto value2 : values2)
        {
            for (const auto value3 : values3)
            {
                // calculate the distance between the three values (no need to use individual min/max calls)
                auto distance = std::abs(value1 - value2) + std::abs(value2 - value3) + std::abs(value3 - value1);
                if (distance < result.distance)
                {
                    // update the result with the new values
                    result = { value1, value2, value3, distance };
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

// overload the stream operator to print the result
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const find_closest_result_t& result)
{
    os << result.value1 << ", " << result.value2 << ", " << result.value3 << " = " << result.distance;
    return os;
}

// main function to test find_closest
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values1{1, 4, 10};
    std::vector<int> values2{3, 2, 9 };
    std::vector<int> values3{7, 5, 6, 11};

    auto result = find_closest(values1, values2, values3);
    std::cout << result << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```